# Connection to port times out despite it being open and listening

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, port

Contabo VPS running Ubuntu 22.04 server, there is no `firewalld` and no `ufw` running, `fail2ban` is installed and configured but currently stopped to figure out what's going on.

I have an `nc -4 -k -l -v 173.212.xxx.xxx 1026` process running and listening on port 1026. `173.212.xxx.xxx` is the public IP of the VPS and it is accessible from outside (for instance the ports 22, 80 and 443 work fine).

For some reason I cannot connect to `173.212.xxx.xxx:1026`, the connection always times out. This is not the case for SSH and HTTP/HTTPS though. I am wondering why I cannot connect to other ports despite them being listened on and they show up in `nmap` like this:

```
$ sudo nmap 173.212.xxx.xxx
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-12-21 16:11 CET
Nmap scan report for vmdxxx.contaboserver.net (173.212.xxx.xxx)
Host is up (0.0000090s latency).
Not shown: 988 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
587/tcp  open  submission
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
1026/tcp open  LSA-or-nterm      # <-- not working
8088/tcp open  radan-http        # <-- Janus WebRTC server timing out as well (what I actually try to set up)
8089/tcp open  unknown
```

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      988/master          
tcp        0      0 173.212.xxx.xxx:1026    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      38682/nc            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      747/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      988/master          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      913/mysqld          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      913/mysqld          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:24            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4190          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9998          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      39690/amavisd-new ( 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      39690/amavisd-new ( 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      988/master          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10026         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      39690/amavisd-new ( 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      623/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 173.212.xxx.xxx:8188    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36225/janus         
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      988/master          
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      940/apache2         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      747/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      988/master          
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      652/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      940/apache2         
tcp6       0      0 :::8089                 :::*                    LISTEN      36225/janus         
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      36225/janus         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           623/systemd-resolve 
udp6       0      0 :::5002                 :::*                                36225/janus         
udp6       0      0 :::5004                 :::*                                36225/janus         
udp6       0      0 :::5102                 :::*                                36225/janus         
udp6       0      0 :::5104                 :::*                                36225/janus         
udp6       0      0 :::5106                 :::*                                36225/janus
```

I am able to connect to port `1026` from `localhost` but not from a remote host. But why? I'm obviously missing something. Does anyone have an idea why apparently all ports are blocked from outside i.e. where this could be configured? I don't remember anything other than setting up `fail2ban` a few years ago. I'm a network noob, btw. Thanks for taking the time! Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most probably your hoster has an additional firewall in place.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. I don't think Contabo is blocking any ports. Didn't ask them directly but I assume that would be mentioned somewhere as it would be a pretty strong limitation. Edit: This indicates that there is no additional firewall in place: https://contabo.com/blog/first-steps-with-contabo/#a-change-your-port-in-linux

Comment: haven't you set any configuration in "/etc/hosts.allow" or  "/etc/hosts.deny" ?

Comment: Also please check you packets through, tcpdump.

Comment: Hey and thanks for the reply! The hosts.allow and hosts.deny files are untouched (i.e. empty).. thanks for the input, you mean tcpdump on the particular port?